# How to load User Meta?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta, author, multisite

Wordpress author.php is not loading the correct information from user meta. It's loading whoever is currently logged in to the blog and not displaying the person who it links to for example:

```
http://www.website.com/author/username1
http://www.website.com/author/username2
```

is displaying the same despite been two different users. I've done what is asked, however I'm still confused to why its only loading the currently user meta and not the meta of the username?

This is my author template:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>  

<div class="author-name">
<?php echo get_the_author_meta('first_name'); ?>
<?php echo get_the_author_meta('last_name'); ?> 
<?php echo get_user_role('user_role'); ?>
</div>

<div class="author-information">
Username: <?php echo get_the_author('user_nicename'); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must supply the User ID when using [get_the_author_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) to get a different user than the one in the loop or currently logged in.

Assuming `username1` and `username2` are actual usernames in the users database table you can get the username from the URL by using the following snippet:

```
$username_from_url = basename( get_permalink() );
```

And then:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $username_from_url );
```

Now you have the full `$user` object with ID and everything.

**Edit: complete solution**

User visits an URL with the following pattern `/page/somename` where `somename` corresponds to the user´s `user_nicename` in the database table `users`.

```
<?php
    $username_from_url = basename( get_permalink() );
    $user = get_user_by( 'slug', $username_from_url );

    echo get_the_author_meta( 'first_name', $user->ID );
    echo get_the_author_meta( 'last_name', $user->ID );

    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        // You can also use get_role( $role ) to get more data on the role
        echo $role;
    }

    echo __( "Username:" ) . " " . $user->user_nicename;
?>
```

Comment: Can you put that into my code above as an example as I've tried and its not working still, i maybe be doing something simple completely wrong, sometimes it takes another brain to pick mine as soon as i see the demo ill know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: It still doesn't work :/ not sure why its a hard one to edit swell as its been racking my brains for the past week I've done a clean installation of wordpress and wiped the database as i thought it might have been that at one point but its not, the above code is still not getting the data not sure why

Comment: Ive managed to get it to work on posts i used it as a template, however i also need it to work on author.php which is the code that loads the author of posts, i need both so the above code gets a tick and thumbs up as you've solved another problem i had, however on my author.php it doesn't load any of the above

Comment: Look at this page to see how you should treat the Author templates to properly load the user data: http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates

Comment: Also the above code is not working for what i wanted it for as well, its loading the recent user all the time on the same pages?

Comment: On http://www.website.com/author/username1 and http://www.website.com/author/username2 what does `var_dump($username_from_url)` return?

Comment: Gives me a blank white page, not even header or footer

Comment: Also it works on administration author but doesn't work on any other username?